# How to build this RMI project using Netbeans?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, rmi

I have been following this step by step tutorial about RMI: http://www.javacamp.org/moreclasses/rmi/rmi.html, and already succeeded in compiling and running this project by using command prompt as what the tutorial has taught here: http://www.javacamp.org/moreclasses/rmi/rmi6.html.

But now I am wondering, how is it if I want to create this project using Netbeans? So that I can create GUI for this project and just run it from the Netbeans IDE. Up until now, I have tried the multiple numbers of way to create it on Netbeans, but each time, the project failed to be run. Please help, as I have spent about 4 days already and not yet find any solution or tutorial that can guide me through.

This is the screenshot that I got after trying to run it from Netbeans:

[image: error]

To be clear, what I am trying to do is "to create a swing client for the RMI application that create and run the RMI invocation in Netbeans instead of command line"

Comment: Define 'failed to be run'. State why you are following a third-party tutorial in preference to the one provided with the JDK.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you mean you want to create a swing client or run the RMI invocation in Netbeans instead of commandline?

Comment: whenever i tried to run the server from the netbeans, theres an error like "Server exception thrown: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host:" .  and the reason i am using the third-party tutorial is because that is the only tutorial  that i have found so far that is works and i never found the one that is provided with the jdk like what you are talking about. where could i find it? thanks.

Comment: It's the 'only tutorial you have found that works' and it doesn't work?

Comment: oh no, what i mean is that it works when i run it using the command line, but it failed when i tried to recreate the project and run it from the Netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have finally found the way to do this. What i need to do is start the RMIRegistry first before i run the Server. Unlike in the command prompt where i have to typr "start rmiregistry", i just have to put this line in my Server.java code in the Netbeans to start thr RMIregistry : " LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);" where 1099 being the port number.

[image]

Comment: This solution helped me

Comment: @ederollora glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 3):

actually, you can use both LocateRegistry.createRegistry() or just type rmiregistry in the command prompt to start the rmiregistry whenever u want to use it for netbeans project

Answer (score 0):

'Connection refused' means in this case that there was no Registry running at the indicate IP:port. So fix that, or fix the IP:port.

Comment: oh. i thought that if we run our project from Netbeans, it will start the RMIRegistry for us. could you give me reference on how to start the regitry from netbeans? thanks!

Comment: Why? In production, you need to either start the `rmiregistry` command, or use `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` from within. Why do it differently when testing?